# How to convert Excel data into MySQL query format

Tags: sql, regex, excel

I have bulk of data in an Excel sheet and I saved it into .csv format like this:

```
101,shortname,null,Description
```

My question is how to place single quotes for text data like

```
101,'shortname',null,'description'
```

?

Comment: you want to update the Excel sheet?

Comment: I believe you can bulk load csv data to mysql table as is (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an editor capable of doing search/replace with regular expressions
2. Write a regular expression that will update the text the way you want it to

Here's an example how to do what you ask in Visual Studio's text editor:

Find what:

```
{[^,]+},{[^,]+},{[^,]+},{[^,]+}
```

Replace with:

```
\1,'\2',\3,'\4'
```

If you have some other editor, go check its documentation on regular expressions.

For VIM check out [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/), something like this might work:

```
s:\([^,]\+\),\([^,]\+\),\([^,]\+\),\([^,]\+\):\1,'\2',\3,'\4':
```

Answer (score 1):

```
101,shortname,null,Description
```

1) Is this in the single cell or different cells in excel?
2) Do you want to update the excel sheet or just want to put that data in mysql?

If you want to take data from excel and put it into mysql you can use apache-poi libraries.
[apache-poi](http://poi.apache.org/)

I used this library to update the excel sheet from mysql database.

Comment: those are different cells in Excel

Comment: so you want your csv data to add a single quote and restore in the same file? I this is so, simply copy/cut that column in some other column.

Answer (score 0):

so you want your csv data to add a single quote and restore in the same file? I this is so, simply copy/cut that column in some other column and use an excel formula like suppose you have your *shortname* in column B cut-paste it to column Z and use formula `=CONCATENATE("'",Z#,"'")` # is the row number